# Why the reactjs/mobx code does not rerender when I use fat arrow for the render method?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import * as mobx from 'mobx';
import * as mobxReact from 'mobx-react';
import classNames from 'classnames';

import './CssClassApp.css';


@mobxReact.observer
export class CssClassApp extends Component {
    @mobx.observable.ref clapping: boolean = false;

    @mobx.action.bound
    startAnimate() {
        this.animating = true;
        setTimeout(() => this.stopAnimate(), 2000);
    };

    @mobx.action.bound
    stopAnimate() {
        console.log(`Stopping animation`)
        this.animating = false;
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    className="button"
                    type="button"
                    value="Test"
                    onClick={this.startAnimate}
                />
                <div style={{transition: `border 1500ms ease-out`}}
                    className={classNames('normal', 
                        {'on': this.animating})}>
                    Testing timeout
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and related css

```
.on {
    border: 5px solid red;
}

.normal {
    height: 100px;
    widows: 100px;
}
```

It works fine.

But if I change `render` method to `render = () =>` the border does not fade in at all.

Why? What is causing this error here: `react`, `mobx` or `typescript`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `render = () => {}` your `this` in `{'on': this.animating})}>` isn't bound to the same scope anymore! Thus, your UI behaves differently.

You have to find out how to bind `this` correctly according to your needs. Or you just leave the syntax as is, as there shouldn't be any need to change the method's syntax at all.

This could be a good source of information:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-es6-the-dope-way-part-ii-arrow-functions-and-the-this-keyword-381ac7a32881